# SQL Server Replication between two AlwaysOn HADR Clusters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, transactional-replication, hadr

We got a requirement to replicate data between two different HA Clusters.

---Current Prod Environment-------

SQL Server 2016 Servers

HADR Cluster 1 (HA1) - Primary Replica (PR1), Secondary Replica (SR1) and DR Replica (DR2)

HADR Cluster 2 (HA2) - Primary Replica (PR2) and DR Replica (DR2)

---Current Prod Environment-------

We need to replicate some tables from an AG Database (DB1) in PR1 to another AG Database (AG2) in PR2.

Current there is a bcp script that runs daily once and they need live data, hence we are planning for Transactional Replication between HA1 and HA2 Clusters ( from DB1 -> DB2)

It would be really helpful, if I could get some pointers to any documentation, best practices, Pros and Cons for setting up Tran Replication between two AlwaysOn Clusters. Or any other best method? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16